# Setting SQL Anywhere to Not Cross Join Automatically

Tags: sql, sybase

In SQLAnywhere when designing queries with the query editor if I accidentally choose a table that cannot be joined to another table except by a cross join SQL Anywhere will automatically create a cross join and depending on the size of the tables can freeze up the application for quite some time.

Is it possible to set SQLAnywhere to simply not join tables that cannot be joined except by cross-joining instead of being forced into a cross-join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess the answer to this is No.

If SQLAnywhere blocks a specific function, that would mean that a whole selection of possible solutions would no longer be able to be made in that framework.

Instead, SQLAnywhere relies on the user to know the limits of the various data sources and lets them do anything they wish with them.

Comment: Thanks for the response, music2myear!